# Write a "preamp" with HTML5 Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm writing an 10-band equalizer with HTML5 Audio API and JavaScript. From what I researched online, the 10 bands can be created as [BiquadFilterNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode) and connected one after another for the final effect:

```
var AudioContext = new AudioContext();
var filter = context.createBiquadFilter(); // create the filter node
filter.type = 'peaking';
filter.gain.value = 0; // Default gain value
filter.Q.value = 1;
filter.frequency.value = 60; // and 170, 310, 600, 1000, 3000, 6000, 12000, 14000, 16000 for the rest 9 bands
```

(A very similar set up can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738056/creating-a-10-band-equalizer-using-web-audio-api)).

So far so good. But now I'm stuck at the so-called "preamp" that's always seen on a standard equalizer. For example, this is Winamp's:

[image: Winamp's Equalizer]

This is VOX's:

[image: VOX's Equalizer]

This is VLC's:

[image: VLC's Equalizer]

etc. you get the idea. My question is: What exactly does this "preamp" do, and how would I program it into my application?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How does it apply gain?

Comment: To what factor? Do they add/subtract the dB value of each next band (like in the screen shots above)?

Comment: I read the article, still don't get how a GainNode is a preamp. A gain is a unitless value, when a preamp value (like above screenshots) seems to be measured in dB. The link also doesn't seem to answer my question regarding the calculation applied from the preamp to subsequent bands.

And thanks for your help, but your sascasm is not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 10 band Equalizer within the waveform project https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/equalizer/index.html

[try on codepen](https://codepen.io/webciter/pen/WNbPyrY)

```
// Equalizer
    wavesurfer.on('ready', function() {
        var EQ = [
            {
                f: 32,
                type: 'lowshelf'
            },
            {
                f: 64,
                type: 'peaking'
            },
            {
                f: 125,
                type: 'peaking'
            },
            {
                f: 250,
                type: 'peaking'
            },
            {
                f: 500,
                type: 'peaking'
            },
            {
                f: 1000,
                type: 'peaking'
            },
            {
                f: 2000,
                type: 'peaking'
            },
            {
                f: 4000,
                type: 'peaking'
            },
            {
                f: 8000,
                type: 'peaking'
            },
            {
                f: 16000,
                type: 'highshelf'
            }
        ];

        // Create filters
        var filters = EQ.map(function(band) {
            var filter = wavesurfer.backend.ac.createBiquadFilter();
            filter.type = band.type;
            filter.gain.value = 0;
            filter.Q.value = 1;
            filter.frequency.value = band.f;
            return filter;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this for my project https://webamp.org. The relvant code looks something like this:

```
const BANDS = [60, 170, 310, 600, 1000, 3000, 6000, 12000, 14000, 16000];
let output = context.createGain();
const bands = {};

BANDS.forEach((band, i) => {
const filter = context.createBiquadFilter();

bands[band] = filter;

if (i === 0) {
    // The first filter, includes all lower frequencies
    filter.type = "lowshelf";
} else if (i === band.length - 1) {
    // The last filter, includes all higher frequencies
    filter.type = "highshelf";
} else {
    filter.type = "peaking";
}
filter.frequency.value = band;
filter.gain.value = 0;

output.connect(filter);
output = filter;
});

output.connect(context.destination);
```

You can find the full source code here: https://github.com/captbaritone/webamp/blob/master/js/media/index.js